# How to create a `Sign In` button using Ajax?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I'm willing to make a `SIGN IN` button using ajax. Namely i want it to present something (e.g **welcome**) on the same page, without refreshing it.

This is what i've done so far:

**update2:**

```
<form id="myForm" onsubmit="return signin();" method="post"> 
<tr><td>Username: </td><td><input type="text" name="name"/></td></tr>
<tr><td> Password:</td><td> <input type="password" name="password"/></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="submit" value="Sign In"/></td></tr>
</form>

<div id="Test"></div>
```

And i have a function in the `head` called `signin()`:

```
<script>
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
function signin()
{
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange =
    function()
    {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById('Test').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;       
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST" , "members.php" , true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    return false;
}
</script>
```

**update3:**

Here's a glimpse from `members.php`:

```
<?php
mysql_connect(...) or die("couldnt connect");
mysql_select_db("mynewdb") or die("couldnt find");
$output = '';
//collect
if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
    $username = $_POST['name'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    ...
    //{update $output}
    ...
    }
?>
...
<html>
... 
<body>
<?php print("$output");?>
</body>
</html>
```

The idea is to fill in the `Test div` with `members.php` response. But nothing happens if i click that `SIGN IN` button.

Note that if i create a button which directly directs to `members.php`, i do get the result i want (except in a new page...). So `members.php` is ok.

What am i doing wrong?

**update1:**

To answer the questions in the comments, the `Network` tab shows `200` `(OK)`.

Anyway, i figured what's causing the problem:

`members.php` should receive 2 variables. With the button `SIGN IN` i've created, i'm not sending anything. That's why nothing's happening. On the other hand, as i said, a normal button like the following, works (because i'm sending the 2 fields):

```
<form id="myForm" action="members.php" method="post" > 
<tr><td>Username: </td><td><input type="text" name="name"/></td></tr>
<tr><td> Password:</td><td> <input type="password" name="password"/></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="submit" value="Sign In"/></td></tr>
</form>
```

But i can't set `action="signin()"` here. I get an error:

*Not Found*

*The requested URL /webDesignProject/signin() was not found on this server.*

So how can i make the button call the funcion `signin()`?

Comment: That shouldn'T be the issue, but: declaring new variables without using the `var`keyword is bad practice. It does work, and in your case (where you specify a global variable anyway) it deosn'T even make a difference. But: This does always create new properties of `window`, nullifing function-level scope. YOu shouldn't use a global variable here anyway, create a new `XMLHttpRequest` each time you call `signin` and store it in a local variable.

Comment: What does the browser's error console say? What does the browser's developer tools' Net tab say? Can you see the HTTP request being made?

Comment: You can also help us helping you by provoding a jsFiddle to test it.

Comment: Please see **update** above.

Comment: @JohannesH. i dunno what's a jsFiddle.

Comment: i could type jsFiddle in google and get that website. still, it means nothing to me.

Comment: Good luck with fiddle :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: I made a mistake in the code, fix it now. if it not working try again now.

Try this code:
member.php will get  `$_REQUEST['name']` and `$_REQUEST['password']` values.

```
<script>
function signin()   {
var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
var pw= document.getElementById('password').value;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)  {
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else    {
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
    document.getElementById("Test").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("POST","members.php?name="+name+ "&password="+pw,true);
xmlhttp.send();
return false;
}
</script>
<form id="myForm" onsubmit="return signin();" method="post"> 
<tr><td>Username: </td><td><input type="text" name="name" id="name"/></td></tr>
<tr><td> Password:</td><td> <input type="password" name="password" id="password"/></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="submit" value="Sign In"/></td></tr>
</form>

<div id="Test"></div>
```

Comment: Still not working. The button does nothing. Please see **update3**; i added a brief of `members.php`. It might help understand the problem.

Comment: @AlaaM. Replace `$_POST` with `$_REQUEST`

Comment: @AlaaM. Try replacing `<?php print("$output");?>` with `<?php echo $output;?>`. and if it still dosen't work try to `echo "test";` with no condition to see if that's working.

Comment: didn't help. and i tried `echo"test";` just after `<?php`, but also nothing happened. so the problem is in the function `signin()` or the button `SIGN IN`

Comment: OK. this I tried and worked for me: remove the `onsubmit="return signin();"` from the form tag. add to the submit input tag this: `onclick="return signin();"`

Comment: it's refreshing the page, and not displaying any new information on the screen. can you please attach a link to your files or send me by email?

Comment: @AlaaM. it's another files. not same as yours. You put the onclick event in `<input type="submit" value="Sign In"/>` right?

Comment: No it was in `<form ...>`. Anyway now i put it in `<input...>`, and now nothing happens. Not even a refresh.

Comment: @AlaaM.refresh isn't soupose to happen. you miss `<table>` at start and `</table>` at the end. try add them. maybe it's the reason the div isn't shown.

Comment: Yeah i know i'm just saying... Anyway, the `dev` and the `form` are both inside the same `<table>`

Comment: @AlaaM.put the `div` outside the table. above it.

Comment: Nothing's happening. The `dev` is just above the `<table>`. I checked `Network` tab: `Status Code: 404 (Not Found)`. What does that mean?

Comment: Did the ajax page actually called member.php?

Comment: oh common!! you typed `member.php` instead of `members.php` ! haha now it's working! Thank you very much for your help and your time!

Answer (score 0):

You cant do `action="signin()"`. However, you can do `action="javascript:signin()"`.

Comment: ok i did that. But still nothing happens. In the `Network` tab i see a call to `members.php` and there the satus code = 200 OK.

Comment: your ajax call needs to have the data built into the URL

Comment: @Alaa the URL should be members.php?valname=value&valname=value

Comment: so you mean `xmlhttp.open("POST" , "members.php?username=testuser&password=12345" , true);` ?  (`testuser` and `12345` are correct information). Still nothing happens. Anyway i need to be sending it whatever the user fills in the fields `username` and `password`

Comment: use vars and `+` operator

Comment: man are you serious? please explain what you're saying... I'm totally new to this.

Comment: xmlhttp.open("POST" , "members.php?username=" + udefusr + "&password=" + udefpass , true);

Comment: `udefsusr` is the username and `udefpass` is the password.

Answer (score 0):

Just add your `FORM` tag this:

```
onsubmit="signin();"
```

Also, add `return false;` to the function so the form wouldn't be sent.

Comment: ok i added `onsubmit`. But do i still need `action="members.php"` in the `FORM` ? because this way it still directs me to the `members.php` page. Anyway, i tried deleting the `action` but now when i click the button the page refreshes and i don't see results.

Comment: No, remove the action from the tag.
Did you add the return false; to the function?

Comment: Yes, i added it. BTW, where should i exactly add `return false;`? i tried both before `xmlhttp.open(` and after `xmlhttp.send();`. Same result. I'm wondering, how is it that the username and password are still sent now? i guess all `SIGN IN` does now is call the function (which calls `members.php`)

Comment: replace the `onsubmit="signin();"` with `onsubmit="return signin();"`. This shoul work. And put it at the end of the function, or else it will stop before the ajax function is completed.

Comment: Nothing happens. It's like the button doesn't do anything.

Comment: That what soupose to happen. so he won't send the form. the ajax isn't working as well? if so, make sure the `return false;` is at the very end of the function. you are using `input type='submit'` right?

Comment: it's currently in the very end of the function. is there maybe something i should include in the file?

Comment: nothing should be included. can you please edit your question and post the full code as it looks now?